# Universal property of Classifying spaces encoded in $1$-cocycle of $EG \to BG$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

Let $G$ be a topological group (for sake of simplicity I think it suffice
to assume that $G$ is finite group. It is well known that
for any homotopy class of a map $\phi: X \to BG$ (with $X$ nice 'enough';
say paracompact or already a CW complex) the pullback
of universal prinicipal $G$-bundle $u: EG \to BG$ by $\phi^*$
induces a natural bijection between isomorphism classes of
principal $G$-bundles over $X$ $\mathcal{P}_G(X)$ and homotopy
classes $[X, BG]$.

Now I would like to understand what is the intuitive reason
which the universal bundle $u: EG \to BG$ has this 'miracle'
property. The key seems to sitting in the explicit comstruction of $EG$ and
$BG$. The most 'constructive' I know is due to Milnor and here is a [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523959/classifying-space-bg-and-contractable-space-eg)
where this construction is explicitely described

The key point I would like to use now is that it is known that every $G$-bundle over
a nice enough base space is completely described by an associated *$1$-cocycle* (see below)
and I thing that the reason why $u: EG \to BG$ has this miracle property is somehow
reflected in the structure of it's associated $1$-cocycle. Let recall the most important
properties of this formalism:

Let $p:E \to X $ a $G$-fiber bundle with fiber $F$ (say a finite set with transitive
and free $G$-action; in our case later it will be $G$! itself).
Let $\mathcal{U}= \{U_i \}_i$ covering of $X$ over which $E$ trivializes, that is
we have

(1) a colection of homeomorphisms $\psi_i: U_i \times F \to p^{-1}(U_i)$ compatible
with projection $p$

(2) the *$1$-cycle* (ie the set of *transition functions*) $g_{ij}: U_j \cap U_i \to G$
such that for every $(x, f) \in (U_j \cap U_i) \times F$ we have

$$ \psi_j^{-1}  \circ \psi_i (x,f) = (x, (g_{ji}(x))(f))$$

(3) the transition functions satisfy $g_{ii} = e_G$ (constant function),
$g_{ji}= g_{ij}^{-1}$ and $g_{kj} \cdot g_{ji}= g_{ki}$

Moreover two $G$-bundles $E_1, E_2$ over same base $X$ are isomorphic
if there exist fine enough covering $\{U_i \}_i$ of $X$ such that
there eist a family $g_i: U_i \to G$ with

$$ g^2_{ij} = g_i \cdot g^1_{ij} \cdot g_j^{-1}  $$

where $\{g^1_{ij}\}$ and $\{g^2_{ij}\}$ are $1$-cycles of $E_1$ and $E_2$.

So our task is to check
that for every principal $G$-bundle $E \to X$ with
cover $\{U_i\}_i$ and $1$-cycle $\{g^E_{ij}\}$ there exist a
and contunuous map $f:X \to BG$ and a covering $\{V_i\}_i$ of $BG$
with $1$-cycle $\{g^u_{ij}\}$
fine enough such that it induces via taking preimages a finer cover $\{ f^{-1}(V_i)\}_i$ than
$\{ U_i \}_i$, such that
the refinened $1$-cycle $\{\overline{g}^E_{ij}\}$ over $\{f^{-1}(V_i)\}_i$
differs from pullback $1$-cycle $\{(g^u \circ f)_{ij}\}$ only
by a conjugation by the family $g_i: f^{-1}(V_i) \to G$ such that

$$ \overline{g}^E_{ij} = g_i \cdot (g^u \circ f)_{ij} \cdot g_j^{-1}  $$

How to prove it? Or let me ask a relataded quetion. In which sense are the
$1$-cycles $EG$ of more 'flexiblel' such we can hit every $1$-cocycle via
pullback?